Azure App Service deployment directly from a ZIP package
We were testing the scenario of directly deploying .zip files to the app services slot and slot swapping.
First we tried to deploy the .zip file to the staging slot and the idea was to swap staging with production slot once the staging slot is deployed.
We used below CLI commands to set WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE="1" and deploy the .zip file which got succeeded from the command line.
But the application is not loading when we tried to access the staging slot url. its giving default MS application frontend page and not ours.
Note:-
We are able to find the .zip file uploaded to the home/data/SitePackages,  directory with the packagetemplate.txt file as the document says.
az webapp config set --resource-group myapp-rg --name myapp --slot staging --linux-fx-version "NODE|18-lts"

az webapp config set --resource-group myapp-rg --name myapp --slot staging --startup-file "pm2 start /home/site/wwwroot/xxxx.js --no-daemon"

•   Set the Environment Variable for the WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE:
    az webapp config appsettings set --resource-group myapp-rg --name myapp --slot staging --settings WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE="1"

•   Deploy the .zip Artifact:
   az webapp deployment source config-zip -g myapp-rg -n myapp --slot staging --src myapp.zip


What is the framework and version of your web application?

Its NodeJs application and Node18 Runtime

Are you deploying to an Azure Web App on Windows or Linux?

Please check the Log Stream for errors.

Linux web app , we are deploying node18 package.zip. Which is working normaly with az web app deploy command. But not working with az webapp deployment source config-zip as the document https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/deploy-run-package says.

Please share the code what you have tried.

There is no Log stream  with errors. Only Info's. because the default MS hosted app is already running in this webapp. We could see that the .zip file got uploaded to the home/data/SitePackages, directory with the packagetemplate.txt file

When I used the Below command, I got deprecated warning.
 az webapp deployment source config-zip -g  <ResourceGroupName> -n <WebAppName> --slot <SlotName> --src <ZipfilePath>


I referred this Ms Doc  and used the below commands to enable Run From Package and deploy the ZIP file to the Web App slot:
 az webapp config appsettings set --resource-group <ResourceGroupNam> --name <WebAppName> --slot <SlotName> --settings WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE="1"

az webapp deploy --resource-group <ResourceGroupNam> --name <WebAppName> --slot <SlotName> --src-path <ZipPath>

Make sure to define the PORT in index.js file using an environment variable like this:
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000;
index.js:
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000;
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.send('Hello, World!');
});
app.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log(`Server is running on http://localhost:${PORT}`);
});

Use below startup script in package.json.
 "scripts": { "start": "node index.js" }
package.json:
{
  "name": "my-node-project",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node index.js"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.21.1"
  }
}

It is successfully deployed to Azure Web app as shown below.

To check the logs, go to Azure Web App -> Deployment slots -> staging slot -> Monitoring -> Log stream.
Check for any errors related to deployment and other issues.


Azure Output:


No. The normal azureweb app deploy command will deploy the packages to /home/site/wwwroot directory only and which may have some issues due to the lock file and cache issues. That kind of issues we are currently facing and hence we are looking for direct deploy from .zip files as described in MS site.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/deploy-run-package

@Vownee No, az webapp deploy command not deploying to site/wwwroot folder after running this command
az webapp config appsettings set --resource-group <ResourceGroupNam> --name <WebAppName> --slot <SlotName> --settings WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE="1", check this image.

Command didn't work for me without the parameter "--type=zip".
finally i deployed using as below.az webapp deploy --resource-group myapp-rg --name myapp --slot staging-test2  --src-path  myapp.zip --type=zip
But this also didntdeploy the app in proper way and still its loading microsoft hostingstart.html and not loading my app.

@Vowneee What is your App service plan?

@Vownee If it is standard change to Premium one.

@Vowneee Check the environment variables of your staging slot to ensure that WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE is set to "1".

@Vowneee Check the log stream of the staging slot for errors.

@Vowneee If you are using a startup command, try running it without the startup command.

Appservice environment V3 with appservicePlan I1v2. Log stream is not showing any errors.
Ours is angular app with a custom statup command  pm2 start /home/site/wwwroot/xxxx.config.js --no-daemon which is getting started with normal way of appservice deployment. But we are not able to do the same with this method.
